# Load a DataGridView with 100 empty rows with Row number at loading in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I want to show/load 100 empty rows with row number in datagridview of vb.net at run time, so that user can enter the data. If user fill all the 100 rows then datagridview can create new rows as it do usually. I found this so many time but not find any solution how to load empty rows at run time.

Comment: [DataGridView.RowCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

```
   'dgv is your DataGridView object.

    dgv.Rows.Add(100)

    Dim I As Integer = 1

    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        Row.Cells(0).Value = I.ToString()
        I += 1
    Next
```